# Serial port access denied

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, serial-port

I am running an Apache web server on a Raspberry Pi. I have some Python code which executes in the index.php file as follows:

```
<?php
system("python /home/pi/python/foobar.py")
?>
```

The python script opens a serial port, like so:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

When I run the python script from the command line on the Raspberry Pi, it works perfectly. However, when I browse the site on another computer, I get this error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

I have done some research and found that most people who run into this error do so because the user doesn't belong to the dialout group. When using the Raspberry Pi, I do belong to it, and I assume that on another computer, I don't.

In summary, how do I get permission to access a serial port on a Raspberry Pi server?

Comment: Did you try giving the `apache` user, perms over `/dev/ttyUSB0`....or maybe this answer could help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25258/ttyusb0-permission-changes-after-restart

Comment: The owner of the server process has a username, so the simple solution is to add that username to the dialout group.

Comment: @sawdust Eventually, I'm going to need to access the port from a number of different computers, and it would be a pain to add them all, so I need a broader solution.

Comment: Why don't you find out who actually owns the server process before you rule out the simple solution.  The HTTP login name is normally not associated with usernames of the host.